# XSL Combine Multiple Fields into New Field in Order

Tags: xml, xslt, element

I'd like to create new elements. Each new element should contain the record key and the First Code Element and the first occurrence of Code_Text element. The process would repeat for each of the Code and Code_Text elements as theoretically, there should be an equal number of both. The same XSL would also be applied to the Opinion/Opinion_Text and Reason/Reason_Text value pairs.

I'm using a previous 1.0 solution from an earlier question, but not sure how to modify it. When testing, I only have access to version 1.0. 2.0 is only available on the server. I like 2.0 as it is easier to understand but either would work. In Java, I would just loop though the elements, build an array or list and then output when I done. Not sure how to do this in XSL. Also, there are many more elements in my file that what is shown and I prefer a generic solution that could be tailored to different XML file layouts. Basically, I would like to copy everything and then loop through the value pairs joined with the record key outputting each into a new element with the same name. I've been reading that using  isn't an optimal solution but do not understand why in my use case. Is there a way to loop through the data, accumulate the values I want and then pass them to an output template or is that the wrong path to a solution?

```
Input

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <Record>
      <Date>10/12/2019</Date>
      <Code>F1</Code>
      <Code>F2</Code>
      <Code>F13</Code>
      <Code>F9</Code>
      <Code>F10</Code>
      <Code>F11</Code>
      <Code_Text>F1 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F2 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F13 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F9 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F10 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F11 Text</Code_Text>
      <Key>12345</Key>
      <Number>09095I</Number>
      <Opinion>O1</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O2</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O3</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O4</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O5</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O7</Opinion>
      <Opinion_Text>O1 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O2 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O3 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O4 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O5 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O7 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Reason>R1</Reason>
      <Reason>R2</Reason>
      <Reason>R4</Reason>
      <Reason>R3</Reason>
      <Reason>R5</Reason>
      <Reason>R6</Reason>
      <Reason>R7</Reason>
      <Reason>R8</Reason>
      <Reason>R9</Reason>
      <Reason_Text>R1 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R2 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R4 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R3 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R5 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R6 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R7 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R8 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R9 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Summary>Record 1: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
      <Summary>Record 2: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 1 Key 1: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 2 Key 1: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_2>Record 1 Key 1: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
      <Text_Field_2>Record 2 Key 1: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Date>01/12/2020</Date>
      <Code>F12</Code>
      <Code>F2</Code>
      <Code>F3</Code>
      <Code>F4</Code>
      <Code>F5</Code>
      <Code_Text>F12 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F2 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F3 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F4 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F5 Text</Code_Text>
      <Key>23456</Key>
      <Number>43095I</Number>
      <Opinion>O8</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O9</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O1</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O2</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O4</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O5</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O6</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O7</Opinion>
      <Opinion_Text>O8 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O9 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O1 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O2 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O4 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O5 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O6 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O7 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Reason>R11</Reason>
      <Reason>R4</Reason>
      <Reason>R1</Reason>
      <Reason>R2</Reason>
      <Reason>R5</Reason>
      <Reason>R6</Reason>
      <Reason>R7</Reason>
      <Reason>R8</Reason>
      <Reason>R10</Reason>
      <Reason>R9</Reason>
      <Reason_Text>R11 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R4 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R1 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R2 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R5 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R6 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R7 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R8 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R10 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R9 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Summary>Record 1: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
      <Summary>Record 2: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
      <Summary>Record 3: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 1 Key 2: This is Text Field 1</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 2 Key 2: This is Text Field 1</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 3 Key 2: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 3 Key 2: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_2>Record 1 Key 2: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
      <Text_Field_2>Record 2 Key 2: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Date>10/12/2019</Date>
      <Code>F2</Code>
      <Code>F3</Code>
      <Code>F4</Code>
      <Code>F5</Code>
      <Code_Text>F2 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F3 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F4 Text</Code_Text>
      <Code_Text>F5 Text</Code_Text>
      <Key>778899</Key>
      <Number>998822I</Number>
      <Opinion>O1</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O2</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O3</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O4</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O5</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O6</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O7</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O8</Opinion>
      <Opinion>O9</Opinion>
      <Opinion_Text>O1 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O2 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O3 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O4 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O5 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O6 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O7 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O8 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Opinion_Text>O9 Text</Opinion_Text>
      <Reason>R1</Reason>
      <Reason>R2</Reason>
      <Reason_Text>R1 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Reason_Text>R2 Text</Reason_Text>
      <Summary>Record 1: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
      <Text_Field_1>Record 3 Key 1: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
      <Text_Field_2>Record 3 Key 1: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
   </Record>
</Data>
```

Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <Record>
        <Date>10/12/2019</Date>
        <Code>F1</Code>
        <Code>F2</Code>
        <Code>F13</Code>
        <Code>F9</Code>
        <Code>F10</Code>
        <Code>F11</Code>
        <Code_Text>F1 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F2 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F13 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F9 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F10 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F11 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Combined>12345|F1|F1 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>12345|F2|F2 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>12345|F13|F13 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>12345|F9|F9 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>12345|F10|F10 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>12345|F11|F11 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Key>12345</Key>
        <Number>09095I</Number>
        <Opinion>O1</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O2</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O3</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O4</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O5</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O7</Opinion>
        <Opinion_Text>O1 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O2 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O3 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O4 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O5 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O7 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Combined>12345|O1|O1 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>12345|O2|O2 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>12345|O3|O3 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>12345|O4|O4 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>12345|O5|O5 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>12345|O7|O7 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Reason>R1</Reason>
        <Reason>R2</Reason>
        <Reason>R4</Reason>
        <Reason>R3</Reason>
        <Reason>R5</Reason>
        <Reason>R6</Reason>
        <Reason>R7</Reason>
        <Reason>R8</Reason>
        <Reason>R9</Reason>
        <Reason_Text>R1 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R2 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R4 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R3 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R5 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R6 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R7 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R8 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R9 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R1|R1 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R2|R2 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R4|R4 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R3|R3 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R5|R5 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R6|R6 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R7|R7 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R8|R8 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>12345|R9|R9 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Summary>Record 1: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
        <Summary>Record 2: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 1 Key 1: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 2 Key 1: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_2>Record 1 Key 1: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
        <Text_Field_2>Record 2 Key 1: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Date>01/12/2020</Date>
        <Code>F12</Code>
        <Code>F2</Code>
        <Code>F3</Code>
        <Code>F4</Code>
        <Code>F5</Code>
        <Code_Text>F12 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F2 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F3 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F4 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F5 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Combined>23456|F12|F12 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>23456|F2|F2 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>23456|F3|F3 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>23456|F4|F4 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>23456|F5|F5 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Key>23456</Key>
        <Number>43095I</Number>
        <Opinion>O8</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O9</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O1</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O2</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O4</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O5</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O6</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O7</Opinion>
        <Opinion_Text>O8 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O9 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O1 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O2 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O4 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O5 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O6 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O7 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O8|O8 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O9|O9 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O1|O1 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O2|O2 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O4|O4 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O5|O5 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O6|O6 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>23456|O7|O7 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Reason>R11</Reason>
        <Reason>R4</Reason>
        <Reason>R1</Reason>
        <Reason>R2</Reason>
        <Reason>R5</Reason>
        <Reason>R6</Reason>
        <Reason>R7</Reason>
        <Reason>R8</Reason>
        <Reason>R10</Reason>
        <Reason>R9</Reason>
        <Reason_Text>R11 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R4 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R1 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R2 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R5 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R6 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R7 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R8 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R10 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R9 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R11|R11 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R4|R4 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R1|R1 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R2|R2 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R5|R5 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R6|R6 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R7|R7 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R8|R8 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R10|R10 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>23456|R9|R9 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Summary>Record 1: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
        <Summary>Record 2: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
        <Summary>Record 3: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 1 Key 2: This is Text Field 1</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 2 Key 2: This is Text Field 1</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 3 Key 2: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 3 Key 2: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_2>Record 1 Key 2: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
        <Text_Field_2>Record 2 Key 2: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Date>10/12/2019</Date>
        <Code>F2</Code>
        <Code>F3</Code>
        <Code>F4</Code>
        <Code>F5</Code>
        <Code_Text>F2 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F3 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F4 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Text>F5 Text</Code_Text>
        <Code_Combined>778899|F2|F2 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>778899|F3|F3 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>778899|F4|F4 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Code_Combined>778899|F5|F5 Text</Code_Combined>
        <Key>778899</Key>
        <Number>998822I</Number>
        <Opinion>O1</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O2</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O3</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O4</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O5</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O6</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O7</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O8</Opinion>
        <Opinion>O9</Opinion>
        <Opinion_Text>O1 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O2 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O3 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O4 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O5 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O6 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O7 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O8 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Text>O9 Text</Opinion_Text>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O1|O1 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O2|O2 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O3|O3 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O4|O4 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O5|O5 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O6|O6 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O7|O7 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O8|O8 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Opinion_Combined>778899|O9|O9 Text</Opinion_Combined>
        <Reason>R1</Reason>
        <Reason>R2</Reason>
        <Reason_Text>R1 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Text>R2 Text</Reason_Text>
        <Reason_Combined>778899|R1|R1 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Reason_Combined>778899|R2|R2 Text</Reason_Combined>
        <Summary>Record 1: Summary 1 Text</Summary>
        <Text_Field_1>Record 3 Key 1: This is Text_Field_1</Text_Field_1>
        <Text_Field_2>Record 3 Key 1: This is Text_Field_2</Text_Field_2>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

Original Code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <Combined>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::Date)]">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="name() = name(preceding-sibling::*[1])">, </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="position() = 1" />
                        <xsl:otherwise>|</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Combined>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use xsl-2.0, you can use the `xsl:for-each-group` function using `group-adjacent`

We will group nodes ending with `_Text`. Use this template (read explanations in comments):

```
<xsl:template match="Record">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="Key"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::*[ends-with(local-name(), '_Text')])">
        <!-- test if a node ends with '_Text', boolean will return either true or false -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- when true -->
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <!-- copies the current group  -->
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                    <!-- process each node of the current group  -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:variable name="new_name" select="concat(
                            substring-before(current-group()[1]/local-name(), '_'),
                            '_Combined')"/>
                        <xsl:element name="{$new_name}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat($key, '|', substring-before(., ' '), '|', .)"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See it in action here: http://xsltransform.net/eiouzkP.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. Also was able to upgrade to 2.0 locally.